# OpenWeather API not connecting using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, openweathermap

I want to display the weather condition of the state i input but It keeps alerting "wrong city name, then displays undefined

```
var button =document.querySelector('.button')
var inputValue =document.querySelector('.inputValue')
var nam =document.querySelector('.nam');
var desc =document.querySelector('.desc');
var temp =document.querySelector('.temp');


button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputValue.value+'&appid=0c712e338cabb3996a78ae788fa566a1')
    .then(response=> response.json())
    .then(data => {
        var nameValue = data['nam'];
        var temp = data['main']['temp'];
        var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
        nam.innerHTML =nameValue;
        temp.innerHTML =tempValue;
        desc.innerHTML =description;
    })
    .catch(err => alert("Wrong City name!"))
    
    })
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: Api works fine , can you please paste your console.log here

Comment: If the input value contains spaces/some characters that require encoding/etc. you should wrap your value inside `encodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error response from the API [1], then you will throw some exceptions in your code at the below lines because of nested structure.

```
// "main" does not exist in error response, so you 
// will get an error trying to access a child of "main".
var temp = data['main']['temp'];

// "weather" does not exist in error response, so you
// will get an error trying to access a child of "weather".
var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
```

It would be a good practice to check the response code before trying to parse the response data, like this -

```
.then(response => {
  if (response.cod == 200) {
    // Do your stuff
  } else {
    throw new Error(response.message)
  }
).catch(err => alert(err))
```

Apart from this, there are couple of typos in your code -

```
// There is no key "nam" in the response, it is "name", see success response [2].
var nameValue = data['nam'];

// You save the description as "descValue"
var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
// But use "description" here
desc.innerHTML =description;
```

[1] Error response -

```
{
  "cod": "404",
  "message": "city not found"
}
```

[2] Success response (if city exists) -

```
{
  "coord": {...},
  "weather": [...],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {...},
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {...},
  "clouds": {...},
  "dt": 1618812226,
  "sys": {...},
  "timezone": -14400,
  "id": 4350049,
  "name": "California",
  "cod": 200
}
```